# How to make my HTML form query to work for all of the form elements together?

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I have a HTML form. There I have four different kind of fields who are connected to the database table and should give result to the users depending of that what they will choose into the HTML form fields.

I have Start and End date fields.

```
<div class='ddate'><p>Start Date:<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="d1" ></p></div>
                        <div class='ddate'><p>End Date:<input type="date" id="datepicker1" name="d2"></p></div>
```

The date fields takes out all the rows in the table who are between the start and end date given by the users into the HTML field.

I have and select field.

```
<select name='md' multiple="yes" size="10">
                <optgroup label="Оpel">
                    <option value="Astra" name='Ast'>Astra</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Nissan">        
                    <option value="Pulsar" name='Puls'>Pulsar</option>
                    <option value="Almera" name='Alm'>Almera</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Honda">
                    <option value="Civic" name='Civ'>Civic</option>
                                 </optgroup>     
                                 <optgroup label="Audi">
                    <option value="Q7" name='Q'>Q7</option>                 
                </optgroup>

                <optgroup label="BMW">
                    <option value="M3" name='M'>M3</option>
                    </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Renault">
                                        <option value="Megane" name='Meg'>Megane</option>
                    </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Mercedes">
                                        <option value="G-Class" name='G'>G-Class</option>
                                        </optgroup>
                        </select></br></br>
```

Here the user chooses a model and the query gives him back all rows who have the choosen model type.

Another select field for the color.

```
<select name='col' size='5'>
                            <option value='white' name='wh'>Бял</option>
                            <option value='black' name='bl'>Черен</option>
                            <option value='yellow' name='ye'>Жълт</option>
                            <option value='brown' name='br'>Кафяв</option>
                            <option value='grey' name='gr'>Сив</option>
                        </select></br></br>
```

And two input fields for Horse powers.

```
<input type='text' name='hp1'/></br>
                        ДО:<input type='text' name='hp2'/></br></br>
```

This was my form and here is my PHP.

The important here is my query.

```
$sql = "SELECT cars.brand,cars.model,cars.reg_num,cars.horse_powers,cars.color,clients.first_name, clients.last_name FROM cars INNER JOIN clients_cars ON cars.id=clients_cars.cars_id INNER JOIN clients ON clients_cars.clients_id=clients.id WHERE cars.id"
            . " IN (SELECT DISTINCT clients_cars.cars_id FROM clients_cars WHERE (rent_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') OR (return_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') OR ((return_date>'$d2')AND(rent_date<'$d1')) OR ((horse_powers > '$hp1') AND (horse_powers < '$hp2')) OR cars.model LIKE '$md' OR cars.color LIKE '$col') ";
```

Here is my query. Its works just fine. When I add Start and End date it takes me out all rows who are between the added dates same with any other field from the html form if I use just one of the fields.

When I use more than one (for example I choose Color: Black and a Horsepower between 120-150). When I do this it takes me out all cars which are black and all cars who are between 120-150 HP and the query dont care about the color of the cars between 120-150 hp and about the hp of the cars which are black.

My point is that i want all of the fields to care of each other. If there is one black car with HP 120-150 to takes me out only this car not all cars which are black and all cars which have 120-150 HP.

Comment: in your subselect, your where's ar connected with OR, might help if u change it to AND so it HAS to check it too?

Comment: AND / OR is the problem. You mixed them up.

Comment: If i change to AND there the query doesn't care about any of the fields except the Start Date and End Date field.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the "AND" and "OR" Statements in Sql .
This should do the magic:

```
SELECT cars.brand,cars.model,cars.reg_num,cars.horse_powers,cars.color,clients.first_name, clients.last_name 
FROM cars 
INNER JOIN clients_cars 
ON cars.id=clients_cars.cars_id 
INNER JOIN clients
ON clients_cars.clients_id=clients.id 
    WHERE cars.id 
     IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT clients_cars.cars_id 
    FROM clients_cars 
    WHERE (rent_date between '$d1' AND '$d2')
    AND ((return_date>'$d2')AND(rent_date<'$d1'))
    AND ((horse_powers > '$hp1') AND (horse_powers < '$hp2')) 
    AND cars.model LIKE '$md' 
    AND cars.color LIKE '$col'
 )
```

Comment: If i use AND everywhere the query just doesn't work. Its opens me a blank page